Troubleshooting Runtime Text Templates: The Missing ‘CallContext’ In Net
I’m currently utilizing Runtime Text Templates to generate code for my Blazor UI. However, I’ve run into a compiler error that says: ‘The type or namespace name ‘Messaging’ does not exist in the namespace ‘System.Runtime.Remoting’ (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The problematic line of code causing this error can be found here. Error Picture
Despite consulting Microsoft’s documentation, I haven’t yet discovered a suitable solution for this issue.
I am trying to find a solution for handling this issue or explore alternative methods for code generation

Don't put picture, put code and even more create a reproduceable example of the problem.
